# Tortoise svn adding <<<< to files!

Tags: tortoisesvn

My problem is that whenever I update a folder via tortoise svn I get the files that were edited and now different from revision 1 to revision 2, SVN adds a "<<<<<<" to places that were affected.

Can anyone please provide some sort of solution?

Comment: Use another program to see file differences. This ensures you don't get this lines anymore. Check my answer and if you like please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 15):

These markers indicate where there have been conflicting changes between what you have changed and what somebody else has changed. The SVN Book has a [section on merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) which shows you what to expect. The book talks about the command line commands but the workflow for TortoiseSVN is similar.

See in particular the section titled "Merging conflicts by hand".

Comment: No, this feature is important to the proper operation of Subversion. Subversion tries to make sure that work done by different people on the same file is not lost, and these markers help accomplish that. This only happens if Subversion cannot *automatically* merge the changes, as explained in the SVN Book.

Answer (score 0):

This lines are inserted by the default tortoise merge program.
If you change the default program to see the file differences you will not see this ugly `<<<<<mine` anymore. Use for example [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)

To use winmerge for file changes do the following:

1. Right click on a versioned folder and select `Tortoise SVN->Settings`
2. In `External Programs->Diff Viewer` section you can set the program you want to see file diffs. Select winmerger or you prefered.

[image]